# Android Java NFC: Read mimetype and tagtype

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am developing my first java project so I am new in this. I have created an activity which reads data from a nfc chip. Currently, I can access the ID and Messages from the tag via this code:

```
tagId = Utils.toHex(intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)).toLowerCase();       
NdefMessage[] messages = null;
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

if (rawMsgs != null) {  
    messages = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];  
    for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {  
        messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];  
    }  
} 
if(messages[0] != null) {  
    String result="";  
    byte[] payload = messages[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();  
    // this assumes that we get back am SOH followed by host/code  
    for (int b = 0; b<payload.length; b++) { // skip SOH  
        result += (char) payload[b];  
    }  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tag Contains " + NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tagMessage=result;
}
```

I would like to add mimetype and tagtype (e.g. mifare classic) to this recognition. But after a lot of searching it seems I have still no idea how to ?

Answer (score 1):

`NdefRecord` has a helpful `toMimeType()` method, so you can just use that to get the MIME type of each record. NDEF records don't know anything about the type of tag though, you have to register your app for tag tech dispatch with ([ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION%5fTECH%5fDISCOVERED)) and use the `Tag` object to determine the type. For a simple description you can use `Tag.toString()` for more info use `Tag.getTechList()`.

Comment: The `Tag` object (intent extra `EXTRA_TAG`) is also mandatory for the `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED` so it should be available even without explicitly registering for the `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` intent.

Comment: Also particularly MIFARE Classic won't be detected as "MFIARE Classic" (but only as a NfcA tag) on devices with Broadcom's NFC chipset. Getting the actual tag type (beyond information about the RF protocol (i.e. NfcA, NfcB, NfcF, NfcV, or NfcBarcode) and the support of ISO-DEP) is not that trivial and requires extensive footprinting.